# Jquery code doesn't work with repetitive data

Tags: jquery

I found this jquery code on the internet, and I'd like to use it for my data. The code basically compares a set of checkbox values with data on the html table, and if there is a full match (all values match), then it selects them. if one of the values is missing, then it doesn't select it.

For example, lets say `1,2,3` will match `3,2,1` and it works as expected. The problem is my html table data has repetitions. So if I have `1,2,3` in checkbox form, I may have `1,1,2,2,3,3` on the html table, and when there are repetitions, it doesn't select and highlight them. The code skips such data. What I need is the code selects the data with or without repetitions present. if it requires a simple fix on the code, and can someone help me with that,I'd be grateful. Thanks.

```
Array.prototype.compare = function(testArr) {
  if (this.length != testArr.length) return false;
  for (var i = 0; i < testArr.length; i++) {
    if (this[i].compare) { //To test values in nested arrays
      if (!this[i].compare(testArr[i])) return false;
    } else if (this[i] !== testArr[i]) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
$(document).on('click', '.all', function() {
  $('#mainContent table tr td').removeClass('highlight');
  if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).closest('form').find('input.selector').prop('checked', false);
  }
  $('input[name=SelectAll]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $(this).closest('form').find('input.selector').prop('checked', true);
      processAllClick($(this));
    } else {
      processIndividualClick($(this));
    }
  });
});
$(document).on('click', '.selector', function() {
  $('#mainContent table tr td').removeClass('highlight');
  if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).closest('form').find('input.all').prop('checked', false);
  }
  $('input[name=SelectAll]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      processAllClick($(this));
    } else {
      processIndividualClick($(this));
    }
  });
});

function processIndividualClick(input) {
  $(input).closest('form').find('input.selector:checked').each(function() {
    $('td:contains(' + $(this).attr('name') + ')').addClass('highlight');
  });
}

function processAllClick(input) {
  var elems = [];
  $(input).closest('form').find('input.selector:checked').each(function() {
    elems.push($(this).attr('name'));
  });
  $('#mainContent table tr').each(function() {
    var child = [];
    $(this).find('td').each(function() {
      if ($.inArray($(this).text(), elems) != -1)
        child.push($(this).text());
    });
    if (elems.sort().compare(child.sort())) {
      for (var i = 0; i < child.length; i++) {
        $(this).find('td').each(function() {
          if ($(this).text() == child[i]) {
            $(this).addClass('highlight');
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Please include your html since it can be very hard to image the problem without

Comment: Thanks. Here is a jsfiddle example. https://jsfiddle.net/6h3au27o/  if you click the first checkbox values, notice that it selects the second row, but not the third row.

Comment: is this what your looking for https://jsfiddle.net/6h3au27o/19/

Comment: yes, your solution works. Thanks a lot, Carsten. if you post it as answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Just happy to help, No need to post it right now. Have a wonderful day

Comment: thank you. you have a wonderful day too!